# Why can't my C# app create files in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7

I have a C# app that creates a settings file for itself to store the current state of certain visual elements. This app works just fine on any machine that isn't running Windows 7, but on those machines we get an error that the settings file can't be created because the user doesn't have permission. Now, I could fix this issue by going to each computer, logging in as the administrator and giving the user read and write access on the program folder for the application that we've installed, but there has to be a better way.

It seems like in XP, you got write access on the folders you created by default, but that isn't the case anymore. Is there a setting I need in the setup package to make this work?

Comment: Did you check that your setup package is marking the settings directory writable and assigning it to the right user?

Comment: you don't say where you are creating files, which might be useful information

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The point is that you shouldn't be storing settings files in the program folder. Microsoft have advised against this for a long time, but started making things stricter with Vista IIRC.

Use `Environment.SpecialFolders.ApplicationData` (etc) to find the most appropriate place to put settings. Or use the .NET settings infrastructure which does this automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that I was doing something fundamentally wrong. I've been storing data in the program folder for years, and it's just a force of habit. I switched to creating my own folder in Application Data and everything works fine.

Answer (score 8):

are you trying to create files in the installation folder?  you should be using the user data folder for data and not the installation folders.  Use the `Environment.SpecialFolders.ApplicationData` folder to get a folder you can write to.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably running as an administrator on your non-Windows 7 machine which an write anywhere. Be sure to save any per user instance data in their AppData folder (roaming if it should follow them from computer to computer, or local if its a cache or local to taht machine only). If you need to share settings between users, use the C:\ProgramData folder with the appropriate permissions.

A program shouldn't try to store settings in its installation directory.

Be sure to use the [SpecialFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) along with [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) to get the right locations needed. You should never hard code paths because they can be different between versions AND languages. (I know in the German version of XP it wasn't `Program Files` but `Programme`!)

Answer (score 3):

> this app works just fine on any machine that isn't running Windows 7

Wrong!  It only works on those machines *if you run as administrator*.  I think you'll find your program is broken on Windows XP as well if you try to run it on just about any business computer rather than a home computer.

Instead, this kind of information needs to go in one of the special Application Data folders.

Answer (score 2):

This is a security flaw in your program because your program is writing information to the program directory (which is, and should be, protected.)  If it's a situation of correcting the root cause, consider using the [SpecialFolder enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) or the static members on [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application_properties.aspx) like like [CommonAppDataPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.commonappdatapath.aspx) to write your information to a more appropriate location.

Assuming the typical approach to writing a file via a path, this is a trivial fix and there's no good "expediency" reason to not correct the root cause.  If you're not sure about how to manipulate the path, consider using [Path.Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx).  It does it for you.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you shouldn't be writing program data to any folder underneath Program Files (even if you created the folder).  You should use the [`Environment.GetFolderPath(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) to figure out where to put your application specific data.  You can pass in one of many enums defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) -- you probably want `Environtment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`

Answer (score 2):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not see how any of this is an actaul answer. I need to be able to write a report and have it saved the users documents folder the same folder I used to read the xml files I am writing the report from.

Comment: So you wrote an *answer* just to say that? Please use comments or ask a new question (yes, you still can't access comments, you'll need to provide some real answers or ask good questions first in order to gain rep)